# How to get multiple arrays from an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, lumen

I have he next array looks like:

```
array:50 [▼
  0 => array:39 [▶]
  1 => array:39 [▶]
  2 => array:39 [▶]
]
```

So I want to get arrays with a value in common, for example:

```
array:39 [▼
    "id" => 121
    "user" => 368
]
array:39 [▼
    "id" => 121
    "user" => 3687
]
array:39 [▼
    "id" => 500
    "user" => 452
]
```

I want to get the two arrays with the attribute
id 121, I was trying to looping the array with foreach looks like:

```
foreach ($info as $val){
       foreach($info as $f ){
           if($f["id"]==$val["id"]){
                //get the multiple arrays
           }
       }
}
```

So, I can't get all the arrays, some idea to how can do that?

Comment: By you sample it's hard to gues which is which but I's used something like (pseudo code) `foreach($info as $key =>  $f ) { if ($f['id']==121) {var_dump($info[$key]);}}`

Comment: You try to iterate the same array twice, first `foreach ($info as $val)` then `foreach($info as $f )`. The inner loop should be over `$val`, not `$info` again.

Comment: Though, you need nothing more than `array_filter` here, with a custom callback that compares each element's `id` key to your desired value.

Comment: @El_Vanja Your comment helped me to give me an idea, Thanks

Comment: Since this is tagged Laravel then there's also the option of `$filtered = collect($array)->where('id', '=', 121)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections).

1. `collect` your array of arrays:

```php
$collection = collect([
    [
        "id" => 121
        "user" => 368
    ],
    [
        "id" => 121
        "user" => 3687
    ],
    [
        "id" => 500
        "user" => 452
    ]
]);
```

2. Use the [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-where) method to filter based on a specific key's value:

```php
$filtered = $collection->where('id', 121);

$filtered->all();

/*
    [
        ['id' => '121', 'user' => 368],
        ['id' => '121', 'user' => 3687],
    ]
*/
```

Other `where`-like methods are available. Be sure to read through all of the documentation on Collections, it's full of great examples!

If you're now convinced that you should use Collections for everything, check out Adam Wathan's awesome book (and other resources): [*Refactoring to Collections*](https://adamwathan.me/refactoring-to-collections/) (not free)